# Google services fails intermittenly with FireFox

Tags: firefox, gmail, google-search

About 2 weeks ago, my Firefox running on Windows 10 PC is behaving strangely. GMail got disconnected from time to time.

[image]

Reload does not fix it. It just stucks in this page forever.

[image]

The strange thing is that it ONLY affects Google. For example, when it happens, typing "google.com" does not load. Clicking a link in an existing Google search result does not do anything. But all other websites behaves normally. I have to change my default search engine in FireFox from Google to something else.

Typing [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) in address bar

[image]

[image]

The response page to the request is empty (no response). Shift-Reload does not fix it.

I am really curious how it ended up like this. It only affects FireFox. Edge and Chrome works fine. I made sure my FireFox is up-to-date. The problem eventually goes away after 10 min or so. How do I figure out the root cause?

Comment: Have you tried backing up your current Firefox user profile and creating a new Firefox user profile to see if the problem is perhaps one of your extensions?  Are you using a proxy?  Whenever I had this problem at work with Google Mail, it was the proxy, it was always the proxy.

Answer (score 2):

There are many reports of this error. Below are some workarounds,
at least until Firefox developers fix this bug.
Restart Firefox after applying each one.
These are not a persistent and the bug can return.

1. Firefox
   [Bug 1510386](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1510386)
   defines the cause as switching between Firefox Nightly/Beta and
   Release Firefox.
   The solution is to unregister the service worker for Gmail:

   - Go to `about:serviceworkers`
   - Find the entry for Gmail
   - Click unregister
   - Refresh Gmail.
2. Another solution is to reload the page without cache by
   <kbd>Shift</kbd>+Reload or <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>.
3. Clear cache and cookies in menu
   *Settings > Privacy & Security*, under "Cookies and Site Data"
   click "Clear Data…" while selecting all options.
4. Delete the storage folder for Gmail. Mine is found in folder
   `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\2lrpqlkx.default-1624267825608\storage\default\https+++mail.google.com`
   (the identifiers may be different for you).

Comment: At first it looks very similar. But the bug you linked is 3 years old. Any bug would have been fixed by now. Also, Shift-Reload does not work for me.

Comment: This 3 year old bug is still marked as "Status: NEW", so it hasn't been fixed yet. I have already encountered unfixed Firefox bugs from more than 10 years ago... I suggest trying these workarounds. If they don't work, it might be worthwhile to open a bug-report of your own.

Comment: You might be right. I have used gmail in incognito mode for 3 days and the issue is not happening. I have previously cleared all google cookies to no avail. So the issue might be related to cache. But I think this might also happen to be a Google bug.

Comment: If this is not happening in incognito mode, the problem might be caused by some add-on. Try to disable all add-ons to see if this also avoids the problem.

Comment: Tried disabling. No differences. Also, my only add-on, uBlock Origin, is configured to run even in incognito mode.

Comment: You still say that this is not happening in incognito mode? Have you tried disabling temporarily your antivirus? Or restarting Firefox? Or Start Firefox in [Safe Mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/diagnose-firefox-issues-using-troubleshoot-mode)? And at limit save your bookmarks, uninstall Firefox, clean up folders and reinstall?